# css3 -webkit-transform not compatible with firefox4

Tags: webkit, css, firefox4

```
#anim1 iframe {
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0,1,1, 30deg);
    transition: transform 1s ease-in-out;
    transform: rotate3d(0,1,1, 30deg);
  }

  #anim1 iframe:hover {
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(1, 0, 76, 50deg);
    transform: rotate3d(0,0,1, 30deg);
  }
```

It's working on Chrome but not in Firefox, and of course in IE.Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-webkit` is a vendor prefix, and so only takes effect in webkit based browsers (of which firefox isn't one).

Firefox is Mozilla based, and its vendor prefix is `-moz`. So look up the equivalent styles (e.g. `-moz-transition`) and check whether it accepts the same syntax (I believe that it does).